# Validate multiple duplicate objects in JSON-SCHEMA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'd like to validate a json object with the json-schema, but that json object can duplicate its values ​​as many times as the user wants.

The keys of that object can be repeated as many times as the user wishes at the times the user create his json.

example 1: (collection with object)

```
{ 
  "info":
  [
  { 
    "name":  "aaron",
    "email": "aaron.com"
  }
  ]
}
```

JSON-SCHEMA of Example 1

```
   {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "email": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "email"
      ]
    }
```

example 2: (collection with 2 object)

```
{ 
  "info":
  [
  { 
    "name":  "aaron",
    "email": "aaron.com"
  },

  { 
    "name":  "misa",
    "email": "misa.com"
  }
  ]
}
```

JSON SCHEMA of example 2

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "info": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "email": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "name",
            "email"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "email": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "name",
            "email"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "info"
  ]
}
```

In short, what I am looking for is a dynamic json schema that no matter how many times the collection grows, it can use only 1 and not generate several.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using draft-04, I'll quote from the draft-04 specification.

This means you want `items` to have an object value as opposed to an array of objects.

> The value of "items" MUST be either an object or an array.  If it is
> an object, this object MUST be a valid JSON Schema.  If it is an
> array, items of this array MUST be objects, and each of these objects
> MUST be a valid JSON Schema.
>
> Draft-04 specificiation https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fge-json-schema-validation-00#section-5.3.1

In JSON Schema 2020-12, `items` may ONLY be an object value, and you must use a different keyword for tuple like validation.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me-

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "info": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "email": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "name",
            "email"
          ]
        }
      ]
      "additionalItems":{
         "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "email": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "name",
            "email"
          ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "info"
  ]
 }
```